# Codeigniter 3 joining 2/3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter and I need to join 2/3 tables. I can't quite work it out.

I have a `users` table with general user info.

```
user_id
first_name
last_name
```

I have a course stats page with info like due date etc.

```
id
course_id
user_id
due
completed_on
```

A user will pick a course, and then be presented with a list of users of their organization. Ready to be assigned. The user may already be assigned to the course and have stats in the stats table while other users may not have stats.

So I need to display a list of users with any stats to the chosen course, if the stats do of course exists.

SO, I'm sending to the model an org_id (to get a list of users of that org) and the chosen course_id (to retrieve any stats from he stats table if they exist)

Here's my method in the model

```
// get users for an org along with stats
public function get_course_user_data($org_id,$course_id) {
    $user_array = array('users.org_id =' => $org_id);       
    $this->db->select('users.id,users.first_name,users.last_name,training_stats.due,training_stats.completed_on');
    $this->db->order_by('users.first_name', 'asc');
    $this->db->where($user_array);
    $this->db->join('training_stats','training_stats.user_id = users.id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('training_courses','training_courses.course_id = training_stats.course_id', 'left');
    $user_object = $this->db->get('users'); 
    return $user_object->result();
}
```

At the moment, if there are stats in the stats table then it displays data, if there are no stats in the stats table, I get nothing.

But I need a full list of users and only the stats if they exist.

Can I even do this with a join? I would have though so?

Comment: Adding left join should work in your case. `$this->db->join('training_stats','training_stats.user_id = users.id', 'left');`

Comment: How do I define just the single course? from $course_id. I need to have just the selected course data

Comment: You can pass that into your where clause

Comment: No because then it restricts returned rows to only course where there ARE stats, it ignores rows where there are not stats. I need all users and stats IF they exists

Comment: Can you show me some sample data of your tables and also your expected output? Edit your question accordingly. It will help to write query at my end.

Comment: You need stats only for that $course_id & for none other course. Also you need all users of the $org_id & not only those who have stats for that $course_id? Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
// get users for an org along with stats
public function get_course_user_data($org_id,$course_id) {
    $this->db->select('users.id,users.first_name,users.last_name,training_stats.due,training_stats.completed_on');
    $this->db->order_by('users.first_name', 'asc');
    $this->db->join('training_stats','training_stats.user_id = users.id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('training_courses','training_courses.course_id = training_stats.course_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where("( training_courses.course_id = $course_id AND training_stats.course_id = $course_id)" );
    $this->db->or_where( "( users.org_id = $org_id )" );
    $user_object = $this->db->get('users'); 
    return $user_object->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot something...

```
$this->db->from('table_name');
```

after this....

```
$this->db->select('users.id,users.first_name,users.last_name,training_stats.due,training_stats.completed_on');
```

I hope this help